# How to get ALL Attributes from Different Elements with condition

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-xml

```
<Area>
 <ShopA>
  <Income Day="1" Money="100" />
  <Income Day="2" Money="90" />
  <Income Day="3" Money="80" />
  <Income Day="4" Money="70" />
 </ShopA>
 <ShopB>
  <Income Day="3" Money="50" />
  <Income Day="4" Money="40" />
 </ShopB>
</Area>
```

Hi I would like to get with specific value from above XML by using XDocument. I want to get all **Money** values which has the same **Day** from different **shops**. I can only able to get Day and Money values from single Shop (ShopA).

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(xmlFileName.xml);
var areaName = doc.Root.Elements("Area");
IEnumerator<XElement> s = areaName.Elements("ShopA").GetEnumerator();
While (s.MoveNext())
{
 var day = s.Current.Attribute("Day").Value;
 var money = s.Current.Attribute("Money").Value;
}
```

But I don't know how to get all Money values from Different Shops which has the same date with proper coding.

Can you please help me out how to get them all?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Something like this, perhaps?

```
    var doc = XDocument.Load("XMLFile1.xml");
    var q =
        doc.Root
           .Elements()
           .Elements()
           .Where(e => e.Attribute("Day").Value == "3")
           .Select(e => new
                            {
                                Shop = e.Parent.Name, 
                                Money = e.Attribute("Money").Value
                            });
    foreach (var e in q)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0} {1}", e.Shop, e.Money);
    }
```

or, if you wanted to get data for all days rather than querying for a single day:

```
        var doc = XDocument.Load("XMLFile1.xml");
        var q =
            doc.Root
               .Elements()
               .Elements()
               .Select(e => new
                                {
                                    Day = e.Attribute("Day").Value,
                                    Shop = e.Parent.Name, 
                                    Money = e.Attribute("Money").Value
                                })
               .GroupBy(r => r.Day);
        foreach (var e in q)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Day: {0}", e.Key);
            foreach (var i in e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0} {1}", i.Shop, i.Money);
            }
        }
```

Comment: A relatively small change you could do is change the `.Elements().Elements()` into `.Decendants("Income")`. I like the code though, might come in handy for me :)

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
<Area>
<ShopA>
 <Income Day="1" Money="100" />
 <Income Day="2" Money="90" />
 <Income Day="3" Money="80" />
 <Income Day="4" Money="70" />
</ShopA>
<ShopB>
 <Income Day="3" Money="50" />
 <Income Day="4" Money="40" />
</ShopB>
</Area>

var moneyDayResultSet = from Income in doc.Descendants("Income")
       select new { 
           Money = Income.Attribute("Money").Value,
           Day = Income.Attribute("Day").Value
       };


//Loop through results
foreach (var moneyDayResult in moneyDayResultSet){
    if(moneyDayResult.Day == 3)
{
    Console.Write(moneyDayResult.Money);
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get all the money in a shop by a certain day with a XPath like:

```
XElement root = XElement.Load(file);
string day = "2";
var shops = root.XPathSelectElements(
    string.Format("//Income[@Day='{0}']", day))
    .Select(x => new
    {
        Shop = x.Parent.LocalName,
        Money = x.Attribute("Money").Value
    });
```

XPath in .Net is found with the following using:

> using System.Xml.XPath;